# Why aren't unassigned local variables automatically initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, compiler-construction, initialization

It seems like there is no way to have unassigned local variables in your code or check for them, as the compiler spits out `Use of unassigned local variable` error.

Why is the compiler not using `default(T)` on these variables at compile time?

Even if it's harder to do for value types, references types could easily be initialized to `null` in this case, right?

Here is some test code:

```
public void Test ( )
{
    int x;
    string s;

    if ( x == 5 )
        Console.WriteLine ( 5 );

    if ( s != null )
        Console.WriteLine ( "s" );
}
```

which returns:

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'x'
Use of unassigned local variable 's'
```

UPDATE:

For people who claims this is not allowed for a good reason, why is it allowed on a class level?

```
public class C
{
    public int X;
    public string S;

    public void Print ( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine ( X );
        Console.WriteLine ( S );
    }
}
```

This code compiles perfectly fine.

Why is it fine to have on a class level but not on a method level?

Comment: The compiler wants what the compiler wants.

Comment: I think it's a design decision and nothing more, a beahviour like C/C++.

Comment: Would you rather have a compile time error or a (runtime) null pointer exception when you forget to initialize a variable of a reference type?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is encouraging you to use good coding practices.

Comment: Maybe to make sure your are not missing anything.

Comment: All I know is that its defined in the [language standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf).  Somewhere in section 12 I think.

Comment: @delnan, if you initialize it to null and then forget the check for null, you still have the same problem as getting a runtime null ref exception.

Comment: The CLR actually *does* initialize that variable to default(T).  Relying on the default value is possible in vb.net or C++/CLI.  But not in C#, the language designers chose to make that a 'very likely to be a bug' error.  Which it is, many C and C++ programmers have been bitten by it badly.

Comment: @HansPassant: Is VB.net's variables actually work like how I described it?

Comment: @JoanVenge: Yes. But that doesn't mean having the compiler catch a subset of such problems is completely worthless.

Comment: The fields in your class example are public. How would the compiler know they weren't going to be initialized before they're used?

Answer (score 7):

I see you've updated your question, so I'll update my answer.  Your question has two parts, one relating to `local variables` and the other to `instance variables on a class instance`.  First, however, this isn't really a compiler design decision, but rather a language design decision.

[Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) Section 12.3.1/12.3.2

### Local Variables

We know *why* you can define a variable without giving it a value.  One reason, an example of something like this:

```
int x;
// do stuff
x = 5;  // Wow, I can initialize it later!
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The standard defines why this is valid code.  Now, I'm not on the C# design team, but it makes good sense why they wouldn't automatically initialize the code for you (besides the performance hit when you actually *didn't* want it to be automatically initialized).

Say the code above was your intention, but you forgot to initialize `x = 5;`.  If the compiler had automatically initialized the variable for you, the code would compile, but it would do nothing like you would expect.

Granted this is a trivial example, but this was a *very good* design decision from the language designers, as it would save many headaches trying to figure out why something wasn't working as expected.

As a side note, I can't think of a reason why you would want to define the code without assigned something to it, or use the default value (in every case), to me that would likely be a bug, which I'm sure is what the compiler designers may have determined.

### Class Instance Variables

Class level members are defined by the standard to be initially assigned.  In fact, to be fair, local variables outside those declared in a `catch`, `foreach` or `using` statement are initially unassigned.  So really, this is a standards issue, not a compiler issue.

If I were to try and guess why this is the case with regards to instance variables of class instances, I would say it has to do with how the memory is allocated on the heap, since that is where the classes are allocated.  When a class is allocated on the heap, all of its members have to be initialized and allocated on the heap with it.  It's not just ok to do it in a class member than a local variable, it *has* to be done this way.  They simply *cannot* be left unassigned.

Comment: Thanks, I added more detail to address this. Why is it ok to have this on a class level? If I forget to initialize the same variables, I should still see an unexpected behavior?

Comment: @JoanVenge - I've added a response to your edit.  Granted, its still a guess, but I think it's probably valid.

Answer (score 6):

C# is a "pit of success" language.

This is a design decision, as the language is completely capable of allowing you to use locals that have not been explicitly assigned. However, it is normally true that usage of such variables is erroneous, that a code path has not set a value for some reason. To avoid such errors, the compiler requires that all locals be assigned before being used.

Comment: Non-stack variables are guaranteed initialized to whatever binary zero represents for the given type (typically 0, null, ...).

Answer (score 5):

> 1 Why does the compiler not allow the use of uninitialized variables?

Because preventing that promotes good programming.

> 2 Why does the compiler allow the use of uninitialized class members?

Because it's not possible to track this with any accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

By taking your suggestion of initializing reference types to null, instead of the current behavior (buggy code causes a compile time error), you'll instead get a runtime error when you dereference an uninitialized variable. Is that really what you want?

Comment: If you didn't initialize a variable and know that the compiler will initialize it to null for you, then you wouldn't have a runtime null ref exception more than if you initialize it to null and then forget to check for it.

Comment: @JoanVenge there is a difference between conciously making a decision and having someone else take it for you.

Comment: @JoanVenge You seem to presume that you won't ever make a mistake. Since I'm human and *do* make mistakes, I'd like to find out about them at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @CraigStuntz: I added more detail to the question. I don't presume making no mistakes but why is this allowed on a class level?

Comment: @JoanVenge The "more detail" totally changes the question. The reasoning is different at a class level. At a class level, all fields must be assigned when constructors run, or you can't refer to fields in a constructor. Contrast with languages like C++, which don't allow use of virtual members in constructors, or Scala, which provides ways to assign members in a predictable way.

Comment: Thanks, but I can see people making the same mistakes at the class level. People assume initialized variables at the class level, why wouldn't they assume the same for variables at the method level?

Comment: @JoanVenge: People do indeed make that mistake at the class level. Nowhere has anyone claimed that C# prevents you from making any mistake. But your suggested change would make this worse, not better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
void blah(IDictionary<int,int> dict)
{
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    if ((i & 11) != 0)
    {
        int j;
        dict.TryGetValue(i, out j);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0}",j);
        j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose that the `TryGetValue` method of the passed-in implementation of `IDictionary<int,int>` never actually writes to `j` [not possible if it's written in C#, but possible if it's written in another language].  What should one expect the code to print?

Nothing in the C# standard requires that `j` be maintained when code leaves the `if` statement, but nothing requires that it be reset to zero between loop iterations.  Mandating either course of action would impose additional costs in some cases.  Rather than doing either, the Standard simply allows that when `TryGetValue` is called, `j` may arbitrarily hold zero or the last value it held when it was in scope.  Such an approach avoids unnecessary costs, but would be awkward if code were allowed to see the value of `j` between the time it re-enters scope and the time it is written (the fact that passing an uninitialized variable as an `out` parameter to code written in another language will expose its value was likely unintentional).

Answer (score -1):

Because what do you want in there? you want x to be zero by default and I want it to be 5...

if they assign 0 to int(s) and all the world starts assuming so, then they will change to -1 at some point and this will break so many applications around the globe.

in VB6 variables were assigned to something by default I think, and it was not as good as it seemed to be.

when you use C#, or C++, you assign the value with what you want, not the compiler for you.

Comment: Well... except that non-stack variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero or null.  The language defines it that way, so it will not change in the future.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why do you not complain that this behavior exists at the class level? Also if they use 0 as the default, later they can't change it to -1. Same reason they don't change a lot of things they did before because of breaking issues.