# C# 'Unassigned local variable'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, console

I tried to make a piece of code which would roll a dice in the end to decide which character wins and it keeps on saying that there are errors (Use of unassigned local variable '**skillmodifier**') & (Use of unassigned local variable '**strengthmodifier**'). I would really appreciate any help. P.S I have only been doing programming for a short period of time on Visual Studio 2010. Please help me find a solution to this problem, the problem occurs because I **use** the **variables** '**strengthmodifier**' and '**skillmodifier**' **twice**. Thank you, yours faithfully, Vikash.
I will paste the task breif below and the code after that:

**Task 3 Determining the outcome of an encounter**
When there is an encounter between two characters the outcome is determined by the following
process:

• The differences between the strength attributes for the two characters is calculated

• This difference is divided by 5 and then rounded down to create a ‘strength modifier’

• The process is repeated for the skill attribute to create a ‘skill modifier’

• Each player throws a 6 sided dice.

• If the scores on both dice are the same, no changes are made

• If the scores are not the same, the player with the highest score adds the ‘strength
modifier’ to the strength value and the ‘skill modifier’ to the skill value for their
character

• The player with the lower score on the dice subtracts these modifiers from the
strength and skill values for their character

• If a skill value becomes negative, then it is stored as zero

• If a strength value becomes zero or negative, then the character dies.

**The program should:**

**• Allow the user to input the strength and skill for two characters.*

*• Display the outcome of the encounter using the process above.
Design an algorithm to describe this process. Write, test and evaluate the code.**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

        namespace Task3
       {
         class Program
          {

            static void loopfsto()
             {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of strength, and then press enter");
            string csto = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int csto1;
            if (int.TryParse(csto, out csto1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + csto1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfsto();
            }
        }

        static void loopfsko()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of skill, and then press enter");
            string csko = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int csko1;
            if (int.TryParse(csko, out csko1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + csko1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfsko();
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }

        static void loopfstt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of strength for, and then press enter");
            string cstt = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int cstt1;
            if (int.TryParse(cstt, out cstt1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + cstt1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfstt();
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }

        static void loopfskt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of skill for, and then press enter");
            string cskt = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int cskt1;
            if (int.TryParse(cskt, out cskt1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + cskt1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfskt();
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string Character1;
            string Character2;
            int strengthmodifiertoround;
            int skillmodifiertoround;
            int strengthmodifier;
            int skillmodifier;
            Console.Title = "Strength and Skill";

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Strength and Skill, please press enter to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name for character 1, then press enter.");
            Character1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name for character 2, then press enter.");
            Character2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of strength for " + Character1 + ", and then press enter");
            string csto = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int csto1;
            if (int.TryParse(csto, out csto1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + csto1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfsto();
            }


            Console.Clear();


            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of skill for " + Character1 + ", and then press enter");
            string csko = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int csko1;
            if (int.TryParse(csko, out csko1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + csko1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfsko();
            }
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine(Character1 + " has a strength of " + csto1 + " and a skill of " + csko1 + ".");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of strength for " + Character2 + ", and then press enter");
            string cstt = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int cstt1;
            if (int.TryParse(cstt, out cstt1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + cstt1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfstt();
            }
            Console.Clear();



            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value of skill for " + Character2 + ", and then press enter");
            string cskt = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
            int cskt1;
            if (int.TryParse(cskt, out cskt1)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your chosen number is " + cskt1 + ".");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                loopfskt();
            }
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine(Character2 + " has a strength of " + cstt1 + " and a skill of " + cskt1 + ".");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
//--- Finds out if strength for character 1 is higher than 2 or vice versa. Then finds difference between two and makes a variable called strengthmodifier ---//

            {
                if (csto1 < cstt1)
                {
                    strengthmodifiertoround = cstt1 - csto1;
                    strengthmodifier = strengthmodifiertoround / 5;   
                }
                if (cstt1 < csto1)
                {
                    strengthmodifiertoround = csto1 - cstt1;
                    strengthmodifier = strengthmodifiertoround / 5;
                }
            }
//--- Finds out if skill for character 1 is higher than 2 or vice versa. Then finds difference between two and makes a variable called skillmodifier ---//

            {
                if (csko1 < cskt1)
                {
                    skillmodifiertoround = cskt1 - csko1;
                    skillmodifier = skillmodifiertoround / 5; 
                }
                if (cskt1 < csko1)
                {
                    skillmodifiertoround = csko1 - cskt1;
                    skillmodifier = skillmodifiertoround / 5;
                }
            }
//--- Tells user to put input and roll a virtual dice (which is actually creating a number between 1 and 6) ---//
            Console.WriteLine(Character1 + ", please press enter to roll dice");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Random rand = new Random();
            int character1RandomNumber = rand.Next(1, 6);

            Console.WriteLine(Character2 + ", please press enter to roll dice");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Random rand1 = new Random();
            int character2RandomNumber = rand1.Next(1, 6);
            Console.WriteLine(Character1 + " rolled a " + character1RandomNumber + " and " + Character2 + " rolled a " + character2RandomNumber + ".");
            Console.ReadKey();
            if (character1RandomNumber < character2RandomNumber)
            {
                int char2st = cstt1 + strengthmodifier;
                int char2sk = cskt1 + skillmodifier;
                int char1st = csto1 - strengthmodifier;
                int char1sk = csko1 - skillmodifier;
            }
            if (character2RandomNumber < character1RandomNumber)
            {

            }

                int ch2st = cstt1 - strengthmodifier;
                int ch2sk = cskt1 - skillmodifier;
                int ch1st = csto1 + strengthmodifier;
                int ch1sk = csko1 + skillmodifier;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look to use ReSharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and this tool will help you discover such issues and give tips or suggestions on your code.  It simply highlights lines to indicate where your code has an issue.

Comment: Task 3 Determining the outcome of an encounter
When there is an encounter between two characters the outcome is determined by the following
process:
• The differences between the strength attributes for the two characters is calculated

Comment: • This difference is divided by 5 and then rounded down to create a ‘strength modifier’
• The process is repeated for the skill attribute to create a ‘skill modifier’
• Each player throws a 6 sided dice.
• If the scores on both dice are the same, no changes are made
• If the scores are not the same, the player with the highest score adds the ‘strength
modifier’ to the strength value and the ‘skill modifier’ to the skill value for their
character
• The player with the lower score on the dice subtracts these modifiers from the
strength and skill values for their character

Comment: • If a skill value becomes negative, then it is stored as zero
• If a strength value becomes zero or negative, then the character dies.
The program should:
• Allow the user to input the strength and skill for two characters.
• Display the outcome of the encounter using the process above.
Design an algorithm to describe this process. Write, test and evaluate the code.

Comment: Sorry for not briefing this earlier. I am new to this and I hope you understand. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, i think your problem is because skillmodifier and strengthmodifier do not get assigned values on all code paths. ie. They are only assigned values from within if clauses and visual studio cannot determine whether or not they are assigned for all possible outcomes. This warning shouldn't stop your code compiling but if you want it to go away you can do something like

```
int skillmodifiertoround = 0;
```

instead of just

```
int skillmodifiertoround;
```

Now skillmodifiertoround is given a value on declaration.

Edit: "This warning shouldn't stop your code compiling" - Apparently it will stop the program from compiling correctly in c# but the same error in vb only gives a warning but still compiles.

Comment: Thank you for your help 5uperdan. It helped me to change another problem.

Comment: @vik1924 Instead of `if (csko1 < cskt1) { ... } if (cskt1 < csko1) { ... }` use `if (csko1 < cskt1) { ... } else { ... }`. That way the compiler will know that control has been through either of the two blocks, and it can then infer that the local variable has been assigned to before it is read.

Answer (score 2):

Its rather simple really

```
int skillmodifier;
```

You need to assign it - that is give it a value, even a default one - before you can use it. Otherwise the program doesn't know what value it has.

So something like

```
int skillmodifier = -1;
```

will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `int skillmodifier` declare it as whatever the default value should be,e.g. `int skillmodifier = 0;`

Do the same for `strengthmodifier` and you should be good to go!

The problem is that the compiler can detect a way of executing your code without these parameters being set.

Comment: Thanks very much Ross Dargan, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Local variables in C# must be initialized before they are used.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Also see related questio [Why aren't unassigned local variables automatically initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797424/why-arent-unassigned-local-variables-automatically-initialized)

For generics where type is not known, use [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx) keyword

Comment: Thank you Tilak for this useful statement. I will try and go over mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other people have given you the answer, but I spotted something else.

Instead of
//method
if(tryparse)
{
//done
}
else
//loop

you should turn the methods into methods that return ints and then...

int csko = loopCsko()