# Global int variable and normal int variable do ++

Tags: c#

```
        public static int number;
        static void Main()
        {
            int number2;

            number++;
            number2++;
        }
```

Why can i do by number ++ and by number2 not?

Comment: Because you haven't initialized `number2`?

Comment: I expect your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797424/why-arent-unassigned-local-variables-automatically-initialized), as it covers how field variables (class-level) and local variables (method scoped) differ in their initialization.

Comment: Yep, `number` is a field variable, whereas `number2` is a local variable.

Comment: this should yield an error use of unassigned local variable which already suggests that you need to assign a value befor using it. no?

Answer (score 0):

you haven declared `int number2;` but haven't declared nor initialized `int number`

please use this

```
static void Main()
        {
            int number2 = 0;
            int number = 0;
            //also possible int number2, number = 0;

            number++;
            number2++;
        }
```

Comment: OP says they can do `number++;`, which suggests that it's a field variable. OP has also certainly _declared_ `number2`.

Comment: oh yeah, you're right